# Can i use replaceAll in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I didn't see replaceAll in String.prototype,but MDN has mentioned this function.When i use it,it will throw a TypeError:xxx.replaceAll is not a function?Is replaceAll the future ECMA standard?

Comment: Check the compatibility table on MDN.

Comment: See the [TC39 proposals list](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md). It’ll be part of the ECMAScript 2021 standard which will be officially released in a year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your browser. This method is pretty new, so it's not advisable to use it yet (or implement substitute if it's not supported by current browser)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

[image]

Something like:

```
if (!String.prototype.replaceAll)
{
    String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace){
      return this.split(search).join(replace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not supported in the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Oh, that polyfill (well, it isn’t really one) isn’t correct for most regular expressions. Anything with capture groups is likely going to produce different results and any non-global regex won’t fail, as it should, according to spec. Using the empty string will also produce different results.

Comment: This is a simpler alternative: `"Substitute X".replace(/X/g, "me")`. Also more performant than `split` and `join`. See https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_grammar_regular_expression_literals.